# Event Sourcing with Credit Transaction if not accept to lack of credit

Tags: design-patterns, crud, server-sent-events, event-sourcing

I'm now learning event sourcing.
I know many examples of event sourcing are banking or credit systems.

However, they don't discuss the conflict between the same timing commands.

Here is the example:

Backgraound

- User X has $100 at 01:10:00

| timeline | payment A ($70) | payment B ($80) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01:10:00 | request Payment A |  |
| 01:10:10 | trace current balance at 01:10:10 |  |
| 01:10:11 |  | request Payment B |
| 01:01:12 | accept Payment with enough balance $(100 - 70) | trace current balance at 01:01:12 |
| 01:01:13 | execute the payment event | accept Payment with enough balance $(**100 - 80**) |
| 01:01:14 |  | execute the Payment event |

if the User X query his balance, he got 100 + (- 80) + (- 70) = $-50

It's a terrible situation I think.

-> Question1. Where is the discussion about this solution about the situation?

I know some engineers propose the queue
or (pessimistic) lock about the table to solve this problem at CRUD pattern.

Of course, we can use these solutions for event sourcing commands, but these patterns decrease event sourcing patterns' benefits, availability.

-> Question 2. Does the event sourcing system use queue or lock exist?

(OffTopic)

Given These problems, I think some credit system needs a CRUD system and a better persistence logging system which can trace the domain flow.

-> Question 3. My proposal is some thing strange, isn't it?

**Update:**

I now know we need to aggregate previous events when we need to validate the `state` on the command process like the upper payment example. And also, we need to lock the writing process which needs these validations.

So that, I propose the table to deal with credit management service

| name | type | constraints |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | uuid | unique |
| aggregate_id | uuid |  |
| data | serialized json or extracted rows |  |
| updated_at | datetime |  |

the outline code of the payment

```golang
func CommandPayment(ctx context.Context, tx spanner.transaction, user_id string, credit int) error {
   // lock user credit's overwrite using redis
   redis_lock := redis_util.lock_user_credits(ctx, user_id)
   defer redis_lock.close()
   
   user_state := service.user(ctx, user)
   if not user_state.is_paymentable {
      return xerrors.New("the user is not allowed to payment from our credits manager")
   }

   user_current_balance := service.user_balance(ctx, user_id)
   if user_current_balance < credit {
      return xerrors.New("you cannot have enough credit %v < %v", user_current_balance, money)
   }

   tx.query('insert into event_sources VALUES (%v, %v, %v, %v)', uuid_util.sample(), command_domain.CREDID_EVENT_ID, command_domain.credit_event(user_id, credit),time_util.now())
   return nil
}
```

<s>I wonder whether we allowed `service.user_balance`to be the same function between Query function or not.</s> I forgot that the command server and the query server are separate

supplement: Command and Query is in the context of CQRS

Comment: now, I know "versioning" in this context, should we produce incremental value as the version in every event, right?

Comment: Out of interest, do you have a link to examples of using SSE in banking or credit systems?

Comment: sry, is your SSE server-sent events or Streaming SIMD Extensions?

Comment: I think that should be obvious :-) Let me try again. You wrote: "I know many examples of event sourcing are banking or credit systems.". I think your question might be easier to answer if you shared references to some of those examples.

Comment: OK. I show the sample project which I learn first about EventSourcing. https://github.com/andreschaffer/event-sourcing-cqrs-examples

Comment: https://github.com/andreschaffer/event-sourcing-cqrs-examples/blob/641cc2714ae7b9c3ebb337c986d3d8a8e3e26847/src/main/java/bankservice/port/incoming/adapter/resources/accounts/withdrawals/WithdrawalsResource.java#L32-L45

Comment: Here raise NonSufficientFundsException Exception on the "past" state of his balance. It's will cause my suggested problem (of course, it's will happen rarely, however, this service is weak than the service using a state sourcing system with transactions).

Comment: Thanks. CQRS (https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html), as I understand it, means one system handles system writes (this is where transactions go), and another system handles queries (this is the side where SSE goes).

Answer (score 1):

1. There are many many ways to solve this problem.  I can't single one out to suggest to you, because you don't say what events you expect to see in the event log or what the processors are actually doing...  but if you require transactions, then you need transactions.
2. Yes.  Payment transactions need to be serialized somehow.  If the event log and view are in the same DB, then you can use ACID transactions to ensure that you are making all 'accept transaction' decisions based on a current balance that is based on all previous transactions.  Otherwise you need a different kind of concurrency control.  Usually this will be an optimistic scheme, like:

   a)  Before accepting a payment request, ensure that your balance is up to date, and remember the timestamp of the last event in the log that contributed to the balance.

   b)  Decide whether or not to accept the payment

   c)  Record the result to the log in some way that will *fail* atomically if the last event isn't the one you remembered.  If it fails, go back to (a) and retry.

Comment: the process c is on the transaction scope like `with_transaction() { x = find_last_event(some_info); if x.event_time != remembered_last_event_time { throw Exception(); } else { export_event(event) }}`, right?

Comment: I think this aggregation in the command process is as same as the calculating state. So that, I feel that event sourcing is time-consuming state sourcing... right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but "ensuring that your balance is up to date" would usually involve synchronously invoking the normal procedure that updates state from the log.

Comment: What I would like to discuss is whether the log in the confirming balance process is a collection of "all the latest logs".
I now understand that if we collect all the latest logs, we should lock the logging to avoid additional logs. it's right?